# How to add padding to elements in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

It's amazing how fast you start using this framework, but i'm stuck on one seemingly obvious thing. In all the layouts i've seen, including [Theme Roller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/), there is a lovely padding on all elements. for some bizarre reason, in the entire documentation, nothing is mentioned about creating this much needed space between the UI and the viewport.

How does one define this?

In HTML Desktop it would be as simple as

```
body{margin:20px}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To be sure, i even downloaded the default setting found on Theme Roller, and nothing happens.

I wonder doesn't jQuery mobile have documentation on all the individual classes? Or at least list the different classes on a page somewhere so one can use them?

Below i added an example of what i mean. It's actually form jQuery Mobiles own docs.
What makes things even more confusing is that the button renders with the button having padding, but not the menu.

To clarify, jQuery Mobile has a 'built in' method to simply add rounded corners to things, you just have to add `class="ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br"`... i'm looking ideally for that kinda method.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since pages in jQuery mobile are absolutely positioned, you're going to have to add a position:relative div wrapper with a margin.

```
<body>
  <div style='margin:20px; position:relative'>
    <div data-role="page">
    ...
```

I'd recommend Google Chrome's inspect tool, or Firefox's firebug inspect tool, to help you understand and modify element's CSS.

EDIT:

With the screenshots posted it's evident that the margin is actually padding that is naturally given to .  This jquery docs page in particular is missing a heading, so you dont see the full width of that.  However if you scroll down you can see the footer is full width.

Comment: Have you used the framework by any chance, and if so is that how you did it? jQuery Mobile seems so incredibly thought through that i'd assumed they'd have this particular part of the styling locked down into a specific class. I'd prefer using there sanctioned method wherever possible. Cheers

Comment: jQuery mobile wasn't designed to have a margin around its interface.  It was designed to be full screen.  However, the foundation of which they built it (html/css/javascript) allows you the freedom to change it.  I personally have thoroughly used jQuery mobile and never found the need to add such a margin.  However I did test this method, and it does indeed work.  Make sure you're closing the div at the end

Comment: The closing </div> would go to the end of the actual page right, not the entire document? <div style='margin:20px; position:relative'>    <div data-role="page"></div></div> //next page etc..? Also i'm not so sure, if jQuery Mobile documents do it throughout, why wouldnt they at least supply it "as is"? seems kinda odd. In general, i need padding between nested elements too, but how does one just define that? for example if you want rounded corners? Easy, just use class="ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br", i'm looking for that kind of solution for site wide padding..

Comment: Since the wrapper begins right after body, you end it right before body closes to ensure all pages have a margin.  Also, I'm not sure what you mean by the docs having a margin - the docs are fullscreen for me.  Can you take a screenshot of what you're wanting exactly?

Comment: This homepage of the docs is actually just one page.  Inside it there is no header, just a data-role=content (gives the content padding, ie, the margin you are referring to) and data-role=footer, which if you scroll down is full width.  It is missing a header, which would also otherwise be full width.    The overview / components are just listviews.  Again, I'd recommend opening these pages up in regular browsers and using the inspect tool to get a greater understanding of the structure.  If you want to 'mimic' a phone device layout, just resize the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem with the jQuery Mobile documentation is that they show you the results, but don't show the markup needed to get there.

First of all, you should rarely add CSS classes directly to your markup. Most of the rendering is controlled by data-* attributes. To give your listview the rounded-corner effect, you use `data-inset="true"`. This also provides the padding as well.

Here's a jsFiddle of the markup http://jsfiddle.net/kiliman/W48wn/

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery Mobile Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li>
        <li><a href="#">Intro to jQuery Mobile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quick start guide</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Supported Platforms</a></li>
    </ul>                        
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Components</li>
        <li><a href="#">Pages &amp; dialogs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Toolbars</a></li>
    </ul>                        
    </div>
</div>
```

​

Answer (score 1):

You can use data-role="content" on your data-role="page" and the elements will no longer fill the width of the screen but have a nice standard 20px margin all around.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/U54AE/1/)

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li>1st Item</li>
            <li>2nd Item</li>
            <li>3rd Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

But data-role="content" is [deprecated](http://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/#content) now. So we are left with:

Old:

```
<div data-role="content">
</div>
```

New:

```
<div class="ui-content" role="main">
</div>
```